# HTML list style

Tags: html, css, list, styles

I'm trying to make a list like the one below, but I have no clue how to do it, I would appreciate the help you guys can give me. Thanks in advance.

HTML List:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: SO is not code machine please add your code and explain your issue

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: At least give it a try with what you think.

Comment: Learn how to create a responsive "timeline" with CSS. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_timeline.asp

Comment: Hey Everyone, sorry, this is my first time asking. I am very new to HTML, I'm actually using Laravel blade to make this, so I did try with the list  element and I got a result but not the once I expected. Again sorry for not asking with the Minimal sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please have a look at the below snippet for the ui design, based on the screenshot attached, hope it helps :)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  background-color: #465470;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 50px
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none
}

ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #A6AAAB;
  top: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 50%
}

li {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  left: 50%;
  text-align: left
}

li:nth-child(odd):after {
  left: -8px
}

li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  right: -9px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1
}

li:nth-child(1):after {
  background-color: #A6AAAB
}

li:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: #EF663E
}

li:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: #EB2E3F
}

li:nth-child(4):after {
  background-color: #158ACA
}

li:nth-child(5):after {
  background-color: #4E2E1C
}

li:nth-child(6):after {
  background-color: #FCBF39
}

li:nth-child(7):after {
  background-color: #B663A5
}

li:nth-child(8):after {
  background-color: #C92F8B
}

li:nth-child(9):after {
  background-color: #F8BBBC
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><b>Sistema Nervioso</b></li>
  <li>Sistema <b>Locomotor</b></li>
  <li>Sistema <b>Cardiovascular</b></li>
  <li>Sistema <b>Respiratorio</b></li>
  <li>Sistema <b>Digestivo</b></li>
  <li>Sistema <b>Genitourinario</b></li>
  <li>Sistema <b>Endocrino</b></li>
  <li>Sistema <b>Hematopoyetico</b></li>
  <li>Sistema <b>Tegumentario</b></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

A little boilerplate.

[There](https://freefrontend.com/css-timelines/) are also a lot of examples and tested libraries. Use them.

```css
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #36415e;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  color: #fff;
}


/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */

.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */

.timeline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}


/* Container around content */

.container {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}


/* The circles on the timeline */

.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: -15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid #FF9F55;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Place the container to the left */

.left {
  left: 0;
}


/* Place the container to the right */

.right {
  left: 50%;
}


/* Fix the circle for containers on the right side */

.right::after {
  left: -17px;
}


/* The actual content */

.content {
  padding: 20px 65px;
  background-color: none;
  position: relative;
}


/* Media queries - Responsive timeline on screens less than 600px wide */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Place the timelime to the left */
  .timeline::after {
    left: 31px;
  }
  /* Full-width containers */
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-right: 25px;
  }
  /* Make sure that all arrows are pointing leftwards */
  .container::before {
    left: 60px;
    border: medium solid white;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
  }
  /* Make sure all circles are at the same spot */
  .left::after,
  .right::after {
    left: 15px;
  }
  /* Make all right containers behave like the left ones */
  .right {
    left: 0%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="container left">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container right">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container left">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container right">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container left">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container right">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.timeline {
  width:150px;
  padding:5px;
}
ul { list-style:none; padding-left:4px; margin-left:50%; border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }
li:nth-child(even) { transform:translateX(-100%); direction: ltr; }
li:nth-child(odd) { margin-left:-7px; }
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <ul>
  <li>- abcdefgh</li>
  <li>abcdefgh -</li>
  <li>- abcdefgh</li>
  <li>abcdefgh -</li>
  <li>- abcdefgh</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is simple layout using list. Try this.